# Passing FieldName as Parameter in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

I am passing table field name as parameter to stored procedure but stored procedure take field name as value instead of field name and throws error.

e.g if i pass value isEnabled via parameter FieldName, Mysql throws error unknown column 'isEnabled' in field list, which shows mysql automatically add quote.

Here is sample stored procedure i wrote.

```
CREATE `VSK_Comments_UpdateAction`(IN FieldName varchar(30),IN FieldValue tinyint,CID bigint)
BEGIN
Update comments Set FieldName=FieldValue WHERE commentid=CID;
END;
```

Is there is a way so i can properly pass field name dynamically properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), for example -

```
CREATE `VSK_Comments_UpdateAction`(IN FieldName varchar(30),IN FieldValue tinyint,CID bigint)
BEGIN
  SET @query = CONCAT('Update comments Set ', FieldName, '=? WHERE commentid=?');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  SET @FieldValue = FieldValue;
  SET @CID = CID;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @FieldValue, @CID;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, its working well while passing parameter values from solution.