# mysql stored procedure executing SHOW CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that wraps around SHOW CREATE TABLE.  My final goal is to dynamically look up the schema name from information_schema and run SHOW CREATE TABLE schema.tableName.

It seems that I can't run SHOW CREATE TABLE inside a store procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ct$$
CREATE PROCEDURE ct (tableName VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

  SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName;

END$$
DELIMITER ;


mysql> CALL ct('users');
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'adcentraldb.tableName' doesn't exist
mysql>
```

---

For those that are interested this is what I end up with for the SHOW CREATE TABLE wrapper that is working

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ct$$

-- Wraps around SHOW CREATE TABLE.  Look at other schemas other than current.
CREATE PROCEDURE ct (tableName VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  DECLARE dbName VARCHAR(50);

  SET dbName = (SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` 
  WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = tableName LIMIT 1);

  SET @a=CONCAT("SHOW CREATE TABLE ", dbName, '.', tableName);
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
  EXECUTE stmt1; 
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You can't pass database or table names as parameters in a MySQL stored procedure. Instead you need to build a SQL string and `EXECUTE()` it, which means you must also be cautious about SQL injection.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993908/passing-fieldname-as-parameter-in-mysql-stored-procedure) for an example

Comment: @Yada my answer is working for you or not?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134044/mysql-stored-procedure-executing-show-create-table][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134044/mysql-stored-procedure-executing-show-create-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass table name like this but you can use prepare statement for this purpose like this-

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ct$$
CREATE PROCEDURE ct (tableName VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

  set @a=concat("SHOW CREATE TABLE ",tableName);
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
  EXECUTE stmt1; 
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```